# Equivalences between walk, trail and simple trail

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification

Is it true that given a graph $G$ and two vertices $i,j$ connected by a walk you can always "get rid of" the extra edges to find a trail and given a trail you can always "get rid of" the extra vertices to get a simple trail?

If this is true, then the following statement is also true right?

> The following statements are equivalent:
>
> [1] $G$ is a connected graph
>
> [2] Every pair of vertices in $G$ is connected by a trail
>
> [3] Every pair of vertices in $G$ is connected by a simple trail
>
> [4] Every pair of vertices in $G$ is connected by a walk

If this is true, doesn't this give a weaker condition for a graph to be connected as you only need to prove that every pair of vertices is connected by a walk not a trail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's true, but it doesn't give a weaker condition - it gives an equivalent condition.

Comment: @mihaild You are right, I just saw it that way because I was presented the concept of walk as the most generic one without any extra conditions and then from there adding extra conditions I got the deffinitions of trail and simple trail